# How to replace sequential for-loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sequential

I'm still pretty new to R programming, and I've read a lot about replacing for-loops, particularly with the apply functions, which has been really useful in making my code more efficient. However, in some of the programs I'm trying to create, I have for-loops where each loop must be carried out in order, because the effects of one loop affect what happens in the next loop, and as far as I'm aware this cannot be achieved with, for example, lapply(). An example of this sort of for-loop:

```
p <- 1

for (i in 1:x) {
  p <- p + sample(c(1, 0), prob = c(p, 1), size = 1)
}
```

Is there a way to replace this kind of loop?

Thanks for your time, everyone!

Comment: `sample(c(1, 0), prob = c(p, 1), size = 1)` always returns 0.  Do you execute your own code before posting a question?

Comment: Sorry, I set p=0.  When I type `p <- numeric(0); p <- p + sample(c(1, 0), prob = c(p, 1), size = 1)`, I receive an error.  Either way, the question is incorrect.

Comment: Ah sorry, I made a change to it when I was checking that it works, and forgot to change it in the question. if the first line is `p <- 1` it should work fine. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Now it increases p by 1 each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of logic is known as [*reduction* or *fold*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29). Consequently it’s solved not by `lapply` (or similar), which is an example of a [*mapping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29), but by `Reduce`:

```
p = Reduce(function (a, b) a + sample(c(1, 0), prob = c(a, 1), size = 1),
           seq_len(x), initial_value)
```

Note that the argument `b` in this case isn’t used — this corresponds to your loop variable `i`, which is likewise not used.

Comment: Ah great, thanks very much! In more complicated versions of this problem I do make use of the loop variable, so thanks for explaining that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a slight myth that using `lapply` will always make your code more efficient. It can make your code easier to read and understand, but not necessarily faster:

```
> system.time(for(i in 1:10000000) x <- i )
   user  system elapsed 
  1.712   0.035   1.759 
> system.time(lapply(1:10000000, function(i) x <- i ))
   user  system elapsed 
 13.941   0.414  14.464
```

In this case, your code seems very simple and clear. So, is there a reason to get rid of the `for` loop?

Comment: Yeah, heaven forbid the code only gets more readable. That would be terrible. ;-)

Comment: It's just as easy to write unintelligible code with `lapply`. Source: my code.

Comment: @HongOoi Sure, but the reason for that isn’t the appropriate use of `lapply` vs `for` but some other factor (for instance *inappropriate* use of `lapply`, as it would be in OP’s case).